# Simple HLOOKUP not working,

Tags: google-sheets

This one stumps me, I simply want to return the "BG" of whichever column has the key.

My formula:

```
HLOOKUP(E1, B2:D12, 1, FALSE)
```

Should give me `BG1` here!

Does anyone know why this isn't working properly?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I know why: `HLOOKUP` is looking in the first row.

So you must get you "BG" labels at the bottom of your table.

With

```
   \ B                 C       D  
2    TheLivingTribunal NowTime smthg
3    a                 b       c
4    BG1               BG2     BG3
```

Then use column `3`:

```
hLOOKUP(E1, B2:D4, 3, FALSE)
```

will give **`BG1`**... not necessarily as practical as expected.

Comment: This worked very well, I just went ahead and whited out the text for the "BG" groups at the bottom so you can't see them. Thanks for adequately answering my question.

Comment: @RichDavis, happy it could be helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers